# Doctrine createNativeQuery with postgres, boolean cast

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, i have a field in my database `is_good`, type `boolean`. So if i check in my database, i can see `TRUE` or `FALSE` in my datas.

I have a simple query with Doctrine and i simply check if `my_table.is_good = $isgood`.

I have `var_dump($isgood)` and i have a boolean in this variable.

When i execute my query, i have this error (in french) :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERREUR:  l'opérateur n'existe pas : boolean = integer
```

And the query in the error message show me that : `my_table.is_good = 1`

I don't undestand why i can't compare `field = boolean` ?

Edit :

This is my first `var_dump($isgood)` :

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>true</font></pre>
```

**I have try to put 'true' and 'false' in my variable, so `var_dump($isgood)` show me a string, and it's ok for the query.. I don't understand !**

Comment: Please show us your exact `var_dump($isgood)` results.

Comment: I edit my post, if i put a string 'true' or 'false' in my variable it's ok...

Comment: Am I understand right, you set up your query this way: `...->createNativeQuery("SELECT ... WHERE my_table.is_good = $isgood")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use prepared statements, if you want to insert variables inside your query. In doctrine (with native queries) you can use the `NativeQuery`'s [`setParameter`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) function:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
// build rsm here

$sql = 'SELECT something FROM my_table WHERE my_table.is_good = ?';
$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $isgood);
$somethings = $query->getResult();
```

There is also a third parameter to set the parameter's type explicitly, but boolean is detected automatically.